# Apply indexed function to each value in row of matrix

Tags: r

I want to apply the function `exp(-r*(i/500))` to every value in the row of a matrix (where `i` represents the column number).  I know how to do this with a loop, but I'm trying to learn the "correct" method in R.

I thought about:

```
apply(st,1,function(v) { exp(-r * (i/500)*v })
```

but I don't know how to define the value `i`, such that it will increment for each column.

I know a loop will accomplish this, but I am fairly certain that is not the optimal method in R.

Comment: you mean each column `i` should be multiplied by `exp(-r*i/500)`?

Comment: yes. for column 1 `i` would be 1, for column 2 `i` would be 2, etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have to use `apply`, then something like this?

```
> apply(as.matrix(seq_len(ncol(m))), 1, function(x) exp(-r * m[,x]/500))
```

Where `m` is your matrix.

Of course, there is no need to use `apply` here. You just need to construct an appropriate matrix.

```
exp(-r * matrix(rep(1:ncol(m), nrow(m)), nrow=nrow(m), byrow=T)/500) * m
```

Comment: just saw @juba comment.  I will accept your answer on their recommendation.  Thanks again everybody!

Comment: @user1790121, since your question was framed as an `equivalent` of for-loop, I thought you wanted to know how to use this in `apply` (as it is internally a for-loop). Of course you could construct a matrix directly. I just realise that that's what juba has provided.

Comment: @Arun - understand.  I tend to think in loops, so that's probably why I asked the question that way.  Again, thanks for knowledge!

Answer (score 3):

Try this, since `col(st)` will return a matrix of the same dimensions as `st` populated with the columns

```
st* exp(-r * (col(st)/500))
```

Not surprisingly there is also a row function and together they can be useful. A multiplication table:

```
m <- matrix(NA, 12,12)
m=col(m)*row(m)
```

Comment: (+1) that's a solution! :)

Comment: My first answer was the same as Arun's, but it was already taken so I needed see if I could do anything more compact.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Nice compact solution also!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this ?

```
## m is the matrix with your data
m <- matrix(1:50,ncol=10,nrow=5)
## m2 is a matrix with same dimensions and each element is the column number
m2 <- matrix(rep(1:ncol(m),nrow(m)),ncol=ncol(m),nrow=nrow(m),byrow=TRUE)
## Compute m2 such as each value is equal to expr(-r*(i/500))
m2 <- exp(-r*(m2/500))
## multiply m and m2
m*m2
```

Comment: Great! makes total sense.  Thanks once again.

Comment: @user1790121 Arun's answer is much better, please accept it ! You don't have to duplicate your matrix to do what you want.

Comment: I still think this is definitely the way to go. But I was just trying to answer OP's question (or what I thought his question was) (about knowing an equivalent using `apply`).